# Passing computed list to an Elixir macro

Tags: macros, elixir

I have a map that I want to use a single source of truth for a couple of functions. Let's say it is:

```
source_of_truth = %{a: 10, b: 20}
```

I'd like the keys of that map to be values of [EctoEnum](https://github.com/gjaldon/ecto_enum). EctoEnum provides a macro `defenum` that I should use like this:

```
  defenum(
    EnumModule,
    :enum_name,
    [:a, :b]
  )
```

I don't want to repeat `[:a, :b]` part. I'd like to use the keys from the map instead like this:

```
  defenum(
    EnumModule,
    :enum_name,
    Map.keys(source_of_truth)
  )
```

It doesn't work because `defenum` macro expects a plain list.

I thought I could do it by defining my own macro like this:

```
 defmacro dynamic_enum(enum_module, enum_name, enum_values) do
   quote do
     defenum(
       unquote(enum_module),
       unquote(enum_name),
       unquote(enum_values)
     )
   end
 end
```

and then call:

```
dynamic_enum(EnumModule, :enum_name, Map.keys(source_of_truth))
```

However, it doest the same thing: `enum_values` is not a precomputed list but AST for `Map.get`. My next approach was:

```
 defmacro dynamic_enum(enum_module, enum_name, enum_values) do
   quote do
     values = unquote(enum_values)
     defenum(
       unquote(enum_module),
       unquote(enum_name),
       ?
     )
   end
 end
```

Not sure what I could put where the `?` is. I can't just put `values` because it is a variable and not a list. I can't put `unquote(values)` either.

A solution that sort of works is this one:

```
defmacro dynamic_enum(enum_module, enum_name, enum_values) do
  {values, _} = Code.eval_quoted(enum_values)
  quote do
    defenum(
      unquote(enum_module),
      unquote(enum_name),
      unquote(values)
    )
  end
end
```

However, the docs say that using `eval_quoted` inside a macro is a bad practice.

[EDIT]
A solution with `Macro.expand` does not work either because it doesn't actually evaluate anything. The expansion stops at:

```
Expanded: {{:., [],
  [
    {:__aliases__, [alias: false, counter: -576460752303357631], [:Module]},
    :get_attribute
  ]}, [],
 [
   {:__MODULE__, [counter: -576460752303357631], Kernel},
   :keys,
   [
     {:{}, [],
      [
        TestModule,
        :__MODULE__,
        0,
        [
          file: '...',
          line: 16
        ]
      ]}
   ]
 ]}
```

So it does not expand to the list as we expected.

[\EDIT]

What is a good solution for that problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the documentation for [`Macro.expand/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Macro.html#expand/2)

> The following contents are expanded:
>
> - Macros (local or remote)
> - Aliases are expanded (if possible) and return atoms
> - Compilation environment macros (`__CALLER__/0`, `__DIR__/0`, `__ENV__/0` and `__MODULE__/0`)
> - **Module attributes reader (`@foo`)**

Emphasis is mine. So the possibility would be to use *module attributes* with `Macro.expand/2`.

```
  defmacro dynamic_enum(enum_module, enum_name, enum_values) do
    IO.inspect(enum_values, label: "Passed")
    expanded = Macro.expand(enum_values, __CALLER__)
    IO.inspect(expanded, label: "Expanded")

    quote do
      defenum(
        unquote(enum_module),
        unquote(enum_name),
        unquote(expanded)
      )
    end
  end
```

And call it like:

```
  @source_of_truth %{a: 10, b: 20}
  @keys Map.keys(@source_of_truth)

  def test_attr do
    dynamic_enum(EnumModuleA, :enum_name_a, @keys)
  end
```

---

FWIW, the full code:

`$ \cat lib/eenum.ex`

```
defmodule Eenum do
  import EctoEnum

  defmacro dynamic_enum(enum_module, enum_name, enum_values) do
    IO.inspect(enum_values, label: "Passed")
    expanded = Macro.expand(enum_values, __CALLER__)
    IO.inspect(expanded, label: "Expanded")

    quote do
      defenum(
        unquote(enum_module),
        unquote(enum_name),
        unquote(expanded)
      )
    end
  end
end
```

`$ \cat lib/tester.ex`

```
defmodule Tester do
  import Eenum

  @source_of_truth %{a: 10, b: 20}
  @keys Map.keys(@source_of_truth)

  def test_attr do
    dynamic_enum(EnumModuleA, :enum_name_a, @keys)
  end
end
```

---

FWIW 2. To be able to call `dynamic_enum` as shown above *from the module scope*, all you need is (surprise :) another module scope, already compiled at the moment of macro invocation:

```
defmodule Defs do
  @source_of_truth %{a: 10, b: 20}
  @keys Map.keys(@source_of_truth)

  defmacro keys, do: Macro.expand(@keys, __CALLER__)
end

defmodule Tester do
  import Defs
  import Eenum

  dynamic_enum(EnumModuleA, :enum_name_a, keys())
end
```

---

FWIW 3. The latter (explicit module with definitions) will work even without a necessity to have module attributes:

```
defmodule Defs do
  defmacro keys, do: Macro.expand(Map.keys(%{a: 10, b: 20}), __CALLER__)
end

defmodule Tester do
  import Defs
  import Eenum

  dynamic_enum(EnumModuleA, :enum_name_a, keys())
end
```

---

The rule of thumb is when you find yourself in a need to invoke `Code.eval_quoted/3`, put this code into the independent module and make compiler invoke this code compilation for you. For functions is works on the module level, for module level it should be put into another module to make module context (aka `__CALLER__` and `__ENV__`) available.

Comment: That does not work. It exapends the AST until no more expansions are possible but it doesn't evaluate to the list. I edited the question to show what error does it cause.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does work for me; I have it tested. Are you sure you pass `@keys` which is _the list_ defined in `__CALLER__` context?

Comment: I am pretty sure. I'll try later today to create a repo with a minimal example. I hope I did something wrong because that is a very clean solution that I would like to use and accept as an answer :)

Comment: FWIW, I have posted the full code I had used for testing.

Comment: The example works! Thank you! I am accepting the answer. Now I only need to check what did I do wrong in the full project I am using.

Comment: Always welcome. Following up: the thing is `__CALLER__` context is an actual stored _context_ / _environment_, and the actual module is needed to store it since one cannot attach any arbitrary data to, say, functions. That’s why module attributes work while function calls do not.

Comment: I figured what causes the error in my project. I am calling `dynaic_enum` in the module scope (that is required by EctoEnum to define inner module) and your solution wraps it in a function. Not sure what are the implications and if there is a method to call `dynamic_enum` in the `Tester` scope.

Comment: That is even better! My next question would be how to move the definitions to another module because the `source_of_truth` could be big! Amazing!

Answer (score 2):

I battled with the same problem a while back. Basically you can build your syntax tree in a `quote`, using `unquote` to inject your dynamic value, and then use `Code.eval_quoted` to eval the macros:

```
options = Map.keys(source_of_truth)

Code.eval_quoted(
  quote do
    EctoEnum.defenum(MyEnum, :type_name, unquote(options))
  end,
  [],
  __ENV__
)
```

Comment: So you propose not to use `defmacro` but just `eval_quoted` in the body of the module? I will have a couple of other cases very similar so I wanted to have the code ready inside a macro.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's that verbose. Note that this can be converted to a one-liner, I just laid it out here to make it clearer. But I admit that I didn't figure out a way to neatly wrap it into a macro.

Comment: The rule of thumb is when you find yourself in a need to invoke `Code.eval_quoted/3`, put this code into the independent module and make compiler invoke this code compilation for you. For functions is works on the module level, for module level it should be put into another module to make module context (aka `__CALLER__` and `__ENV__`) available.